# Django - has the behavior of `Unknown column 'foo.bar' in 'field list'` changed?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have a query that I would expect to raise the exception, `Unknown column 'foo.bar' in 'field list'`; but, now on 1.4 Django, the exception seems to be swallowed and an empty queryset is returned.

```
In [1]: Foo.objects.all()
Out[1]: []

In [2]: from django.db import connection

In [3]: connection.queries
Out[3]: 
[{'sql': 'SELECT ..`foo`.`bar` ...',
  'time': '0.001'}]
```

Meanwhile, the same query in the db:

```
mysql> SELECT ..`foo`.`bar` ...;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'foo.bar' in 'field list'
```

Can I get (what I believe to be) the old behavior back?

Where did I miss this change in the release notes?

Note, that this is not a problem with the lazy execution of querysets, `connection.queries` has a query. Printing the queryset executes the query.

```
In [1]: from django.db import connection

In [2]: connection.queries
Out[2]: []

In [3]: q = Foo.objects.all()

In [4]: connection.queries
Out[4]: []

In [5]: print q
Out[5]: []

In [6]: connection.queries
Out[6]:
[{'sql': 'SELECT ...
```

Comment: That seems odd.  Have you tried to use the queryset yet?  In otherwords, it is just being lazy and you will see the expected error if you iter of the result?  Just a thought.  Hope it might help.

Comment: yes, iterating over the qs yields the error `[o for o in Foo.objects.all()]` .. yet `list(Foo.objects.all())` does not .. hrm .. I could have sworn this was different in previous versions ...

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, QuerySets are lazy in Django.  So, you will not get the error until you try to use it (e.g. iter over the queryset).  Here is a [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) to the documentation.

This is not new behavior in Django.  You can find the same documentation for 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Though this looks like three database hits, in fact it hits the database only once, at the last line (print q).` - printing executes the qs, of course.